# How Do I Add A Graph to a Webpage Using Perl?

Tags: html, mysql, perl, graph, charts

I need to create a graph using data in Perl pulled form a MySQL database.

I've seen the `GD::Graph` recommendation and other ways but I don't know how to use any of them and can't find much online.

I've entered a `GD::Graph` script for the web page but nothing comes up. I'm assuming I have to somehow incorporate HTML to display the graph but I don't know how to do that either.

I just need a basic line graph so any simple example would help a lot.

Heres an example program I was playing with that I couldn't get to work:

```
use GD::Graph::bars;
use GD::Graph::Data;

my $data = GD::Graph::Data->new([
    ["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th", "8th", "9th"],
    [    1,    2,    5,    6,    3,  1.5,    1,     3,     4],
]) or die GD::Graph::Data->error;

my $graph = GD::Graph::bars->new;

$graph->set( 
     x_label         => 'X Label',
     y_label         => 'Y label',
     title           => 'A Simple Bar Chart',

     #y_max_value     => 7,
     #y_tick_number   => 8,
     #y_label_skip    => 3,

     #x_labels_vertical => 1,

     #bar_spacing     => 10,
     #shadow_depth    => 4,
     #shadowclr       => 'dred',

     #transparent     => 0,
) or die $graph->error;

$graph->plot($data) or die $graph->error;

my $file = 'bars.png';
open(my $out, '>', $file) or die "Cannot open '$file' for write: $!";
binmode $out;
print $out $graph->gd->png;
close $out;
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show us the code that you've tried and need help with.

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to write it for me, just help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: The piece of code you've shown creates an image, and prints it to a file. If you want to include that in an HTML page, you'd have to include that image. Alternatively you can use this code as a CGI script, and instead of opening a file, just print to STDOUT. Send the correct `image/png` headers first. Use the URL to the script in your HTML in a `<img src="foo.pl">` tag.

Comment: Even when I leave it as it is though I still don't get an image. How exactly do I incorporate the additions you mentioned?

Comment: You first need to understand how "the Web" works: Servers, clients, requests, and responses; contents types, HTML, how images are embedded in a page etc. Without the basics, you will be lost. What you learn here will not be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample programs works for me. I get a file called `bars.png` which contains the expected image. If you need help getting that program working then you need to give us more information than "Heres an example program I was playing with that I couldn't get to work". Exactly what unexpected behaviour did you get? Was the file written? Did it contain the correct image? Did your computer burst into flames?

Having got that program to work, it's a simple process to turn it into a CGI program that writes the image to STDOUT. It would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Added: Use the CGI library
# (not essential, but makes your life easier)
use CGI 'header';
use GD::Graph::bars;
use GD::Graph::Data;

my $data = GD::Graph::Data->new([
    ["1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th", "8th", "9th"],
    [    1,    2,    5,    6,    3,  1.5,    1,     3,     4],
]) or die GD::Graph::Data->error;

my $graph = GD::Graph::bars->new;

$graph->set(
     x_label         => 'X Label',
     y_label         => 'Y label',
     title           => 'A Simple Bar Chart',

     #y_max_value     => 7,
     #y_tick_number   => 8,
     #y_label_skip    => 3,

     #x_labels_vertical => 1,

     #bar_spacing     => 10,
     #shadow_depth    => 4,
     #shadowclr       => 'dred',

     #transparent     => 0,
) or die $graph->error;

$graph->plot($data) or die $graph->error;

# Added: print the content-type header
print header('image/png');

# Removed: opening an image file
# Changed: Run binmode against STDOUT, not your image file
binmode STDOUT;
# Changed: Print image to STDOUT, not your image file
print $graph->gd->png;
# Removed: Don't close the filehandle, that you didn't open :-)
```

If you put that code in a file somewhere on your web server where it is recognised as a CGI program (doing that is outside the scope of this answer - but there are plenty of good answers about it on this site), then you will be able to enter the URL of the file into your browser to see the image. Once that works, you will also be able to embed the image into an HTML page using an `<img src="...">` tag.

If you need any more help with this, please ask more specific questions.

Comment: This was super helpful and I got exactly the result I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If you know enough about `GD::Graph` to generate an image file (say, a PNG file), then the usual idiom for displaying it in a web browser is

```
...
use GD::Graph;
my $graph = ...;
my $file = "bars-$$.png";     # a unique file name
# replace  /var/www/htdocs  here with the root document directory for your server
open my $out, '>', '/var/www/htdocs/bars/$file';
print $out $graph->gd->png;
close $out;

# now write the web page
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html><head><title>Bar Graph</title><head>\n";
print "<body>";
print ...
print "<h2>Here is a bar graph</h2>\n";
print "<img src='/bars/$file'>\n";
print ...
print "</body></html>\n";
```

Comment: Why is this more idiomatic then responding with `image/png` content type and the image data?

Comment: You need `binmode $out` or `open my $out, '>:unix', ...` to ensure [correct behavior on Windows](https://www.nu42.com/2014/12/when-bits-dont-stick.html)

Comment: Encouraging the use of raw HTML in CGI programs is never a good idea.